# create tables from xml schema (using C# & mssql)

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008, dataset, xsd

Im looking for ways to create data tables in mssql using a XML Schema file to specify the relationships/datatypes (for c#?).

Currently I know I can use the SQLXMLBulkLoadLib.

Also right now I am exploring the dataset.writexmlschema/dataset.readxmlschema,
but I don't know very much on how this works for nested elements

Are there any other methods?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can import xml schema into DataSet, and then recreate database structure using SQL Server Management Objects. There is an [article on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17169/Copy-Data-from-a-DataTable-to-a-SQLServer-Database) containing some samples on how to do this.

Comment: Yea I know about importing xml schema to dataset, but this does not seem to allow for me to nest multiple xml elements. It just doesn't seem to be flexible enough.